# Running a conditional into a true statement of a conditional

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently going through the CS50 course and already hit the first obstacle. Basically I am trying to check different conditions to be true in order for an output, however even if what I am introducing is correct, it just seems to not work.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int test = 0;
    double nr = get_double("Your card number please:\n ");
        while(test < 1)
        {
            if(nr / 100000000000000 < 10)
            {
                if(nr / 10000000000000 == 37)
                {
                    printf("AMEX");
                    test++;
                }
                else if(nr / 10000000000000 == 34)
                {
                    printf("AMEX");
                    test++;
                }
            }
            else {
            printf("false");
            }
        }
}
```

Here is an example that should work:378282246310005. Even if I introduce a wrong number, nothing is being displayed.
Also, I reckon the while loop is not breaking because the conditions aren't run, or is there another mistake I am missing?

Thanks in advance peeps

Comment: Don't use numerical types/constants as credit card numbers. These are too long for standard types to handle. Use strings instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. A US card number fits into a `uint64_t` and is probably appropriate "enough" for an intro class assignment where the goal is to use numeric functions/constructs.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov Intro class is not supposed to use `stdint` types, if you ask me. Perhaps `unsigned long long` will do, but it's a sloppy path.

Comment: Yet `double` is certainly *in*appropriate, and, moreover, floating-point arithmetic and comparisons do not appear to be what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @flodrian, what happens if `nr` passes the `nr / 100000000000000 < 10` test, but not either of the two equality tests within that `if` block?

Comment: "just seems to not work" is not a proper problem report. Please specify the problem exactly: what happens? what does not happen? what is expected to happen? Ideally with cut-and-paste of the actual console output (text, not images). Please learn to do this - it will serve you well throughout  your career.

Comment: Also working from a test-driven approach (and post your test cases for assistance) may help you realize you have a path through the loop which is infinite - e.g. nr=0.

Comment: I may be wrong on this (still checking) but a 64-bit double (52 bits of mantissa) can only represent 15 decimal digits in all cases - where the OP code apparently is dealing with 16 decimal digit cc #s.

Comment: If nothing else, please perform the division `nr / 100000000000000` exactly **once** and store the result in a temporary variable. You can then print this out, which will help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `double` (a representation of a floating point number that need not be an integer), meaning that when you divide it by your divisors, the result is not truncated. For your example (input is `378282246310005`), the value of `nr / 10000000000000` is not 37, but is actually a `double` with value approximately 37.8282246...

The input will not fit into an int, so the `get_int` function available in cs50.h will be inappropriate. However, the value *will* fit into a `long`, *on the environment that CS50 uses*<sup>1</sup>

Declare `nr` with type `long`, and use `get_long()` to obtain the input from the user. Then the value of `nr / 10000000000000` will be truncated toward zero to become 37, exactly as you need here.

### Note regarding types:

<sup>1</sup> The authors of `libcs50` document `get_long()` with a 64-bit signed type for `long` in mind, having the expected toolchain and environment in mind. This is not always the case, especially if your environment (OS, compiler, etc) doesn't match what the authors of CS50 expect you to use.

You will want to make sure that your assumptions hold if you want to use `long` on other environments; it is unwise to generalize that `long` will be 64 bits in the future, without first carefully verifying that this is the case. For the purposes of this assignment, the given type will be sufficient, but you may want to consider learning about the [`stdint.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) header, which provides types that have a guaranteed, specified size.

Comment: I would be surprised to find that the OP's `long` has 16 decimal digits of precision.  On all the popular C implementations for Linux, Mac, and Windows, `long` has the same size and representation as `int` (32-bit two's complement).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Please refer to the [header](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h) that the CS50 program uses. The authors of that header guarantee that on the environment used for that class, `long` will be a 64-bit signed type. My out-of-the-box C environment (installed from my package manager on a popular distro) also happens to make `long` have the same size and representation as a 64-bit signed (2s-complement) integer. I'm adding notes to caution readers to not generalize.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *On all the popular C implementations for Linux, Mac, and Windows, long has the same size and representation as int (32-bit two's complement).* This is incorrect.

Comment: Well that would be yet another reason to dislike CS50.  But more importantly, neither header or library does anything to ensure that `long` actually is a 64-bit type.  Many people do CS50 independently, not in a special environment prepared for the in-person class, and they are likely to find that they actually have only 32-bit `long`.

Comment: Apparently you have a counterexample, @n.m..  Did you intend to share?

Comment: @JohnBollinger have a few thousands of those in the building I'm in. All computers running Linux and all computers here running Mac OS X on the x64 platform have 64 bit longs, and have had for quite some time. I would be hard pressed to find any that still has 32 bit longs by default

Comment: @JohnBollinger Calling libCS50 faulty isn't terribly helpful to the OP. I certainly wouldn't ever use it for my own projects, but given the nature of the question I am prepared to provide a recommendation for what is, given what I know about the OP's situation, an appropriate numeric type to complete the assignment (while giving a warning to this effect). You are welcome to add an answer that recommends patching or getting rid of CS50 if you think it will be more useful to the asker.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Digging deeper, whether or not this decision is correct or good, it's useful to know that it was a [conscious decision](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/pull/109), deprecating a similar function called `get_long_long`.

Comment: You don't have to beleve me. You can just check your own Linux or Mac computer. Just in case all of them are being unavalilable right now, you can  find counterexamples online. There's no need to stretch your imagination too far. https://ideone.com/a0nLeP What do you think this one is running? If all else fails, I heard there's a way to find such information over the Internet.

Comment: Ok, *mea culpa*.  At this point, I have no idea how I acquired that idea, since in fact I use and program for a 64-bit Linux machine every day.  I suppose I can take pride at least in having practiced good enough programming discipline to not have been bitten by my misconception.